# jquery: remove URL fragment on click

Tags: jquery, hash, click

I have this type of hashing URLs,

```
http://mysite.com/projects/#/article-1/
http://mysite.com/projects/#/article-2/
http://mysite.com/projects/#/article-2/
```

And I want to remove the hash bit (the fragment) when I click on a button on the page without redirecting the page.

```
$('.back').click(function(){


    // remove the fragment.
    // don't know how to make it..
    return false;

});
```

So I can get this only,

```
http://mysite.com/projects/
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
How does this [site](http://www.pentagram.com/work/#/all/all/newest/) make it? If you click **close project** on the ajax loaded page, eg -

```
http://www.pentagram.com/work/#/all/all/newest/2534/
```

you will get this back,

```
http://www.pentagram.com/work/#/all/all/newest/
```

Comment: Are you using anchors? What you need to do with the first substring?

Comment: no. I am loading an ajax page using `location.hash` and I want to remove it when I remove that ajax page.

Comment: Regarding your update: If you look closely you see that it does not remove the hash. It just removes part of the hash.

Comment: @Felix: thanks for pointing that out. I realised that after the edit! lol

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

This will leave you with a trailing `#` though.

Comment: @Flix Kling history.pushState is only supported in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari at the moment.

Comment: @timw4mail: I know. One would have to test whether it is supported of course.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: It does not *redirect*. Jumping is different than redirect. Redirection means that the browser issues an HTTP request and loads a new page.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you can try to mimic what would normally happen, I mean:

- on click prevent default action
- analyze the link, get tha hash part
- find tha anchor on the page (y coordinate)
- scroll to the anchor

Something like this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var loc = $(this).attr("href").split("#"),
        hash = loc[1] ? loc[1] : null;
    if (hash && $("a[name="+hash+"]").size() > 0)
    {
        var pos = $("a[name="+hash+"]").position();
        $(window).scrollTop(pos.top);
        return false;
    }
});
```

This way tha url remains the same, but you have the functionality.

Comment: no, that is not what I meant actually sorry. have a look on my edit please. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. You can get rid of everything after the hash by setting the location hash like this, though:

```
location.hash = '';
```

Comment: In that case you'll need to remove your onhashchange event before you change the hash.